# Quartz.NET job instance created but execute never called

Tags: c#, asp.net, quartz-scheduler

I am using 2.2.4.400 of http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/. It is successfully working in other projects but not in this new one which is:

- ASP.NET MVC 3, SQL Server back end
- Based on ASP Boilerplate template (http://aspnetboilerplate.com/)

If I put a break point in the constructor for the class:

```
public class EmailQueueProcessJob : IJob
```

it is hit, however the execute never gets called. I have a break point placed at the top of:

```
public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext aContext)
{
}
```

Looking in the database I can see the jobs being created that they are supposedly "EXECUTING" but my Execute method is never called.

[image: Jobs as they appear in the database]

There is no code in the constructor, but clearly there must be an exception or something happening somewhere to prevent the execution. Any ideas on how I can track this down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution ended up being to configure common logging and then have a look to see what is going wrong. The following will log to the trace window in VS. In my case there was an exception in one of the IJob constructor.

```
using colAlias = Common.Logging;

//Setup logging
colAlias.LogManager.Adapter = new colAlias.Simple.TraceLoggerFactoryAdapter { Level = colAlias.LogLevel.Info };
```

Comment: Yea but you didn't mention what was wrong, just that you added logging to figure it out. So while that likely led you to a solution, it certainly is NOT a solution to the problem, and I find myself in need of an actual solution.

Comment: And what did your log output tell you? In my case I had a low level exception that was not being trapped.

Comment: Same here, have to admit when I'm wrong. The log is the ONLY solution! 
Quartz suppresses the error, so you have to have logging enabled and functional to figure out what's wrong.
+1 vote for you.